# Python: avoid new line with print command

Tags: python, printing, newline, python-2.5

When I use the `print` command, it prints whatever I want and then goes to a different line. For example:

```
print "this should be"; print "on the same line"
```

Should return:

> this should be on the same line

but instead returns:

> this should be
> on the same line

More precisely I was trying to create a program with `if` that told me whether a number was a 2 or not

```
def test2(x):
    if x == 2:
        print "Yeah bro, that's tottaly a two"
    else:
        print "Nope, that is not a two. That is a (x)"
```

But it doesn't recognise the last `(x)` as the value entered, and rather prints exactly: "(x)" (the letter with the brackets). To make it work I have to write:

```
print "Nope, that is not a two. That is a"; print (x)
```

And if e.g. I enter `test2(3)` that gives:

> Nope, that is not a two, that is a
> 3

So either I need to make Python recognise my (x) inside a print line as the number; or to print two separate things but on the same line.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: I am using **version 2.5.4**

Another note: If I put `print "Thing" , print "Thing2"` it says "Syntax error" on the 2nd print.

Comment: Add a comma (`,`) at the end of the line. Note that it will still make the `print` statement print a whitespace instead of a newline.

Comment: Answers arent the same, and most use `the sys.stdout.write` command (and it is a more advanced thread). Since i have started programming today, i did not understand them. (I found several more very similar threads, like 5, but i didnt understand or the questions werent the exact same)

Answer (score 198, accepted):

In **Python 3.x**, you can use the `end` argument to the `print()` function to prevent a newline character from being printed:

```
print("Nope, that is not a two. That is a", end="")
```

In **Python 2.x**, you can use a trailing comma:

```
print "this should be",
print "on the same line"
```

You don't need this to simply print a variable, though:

```
print "Nope, that is not a two. That is a", x
```

Note that the trailing comma still results in a space being printed at the end of the line, i.e. it's equivalent to using `end=" "` in Python 3.  To suppress the space character as well, you can either use

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

to get access to the Python 3 print function or use `sys.stdout.write()`.

Comment: Will this work on Python 3? I'm asking, because print will require parens, and with parens and 2.7, this won't work.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus it won't work on 3.x, you suppress using `print('whateverhere', end='')` where end normally defaults to '\n'

Comment: @Jon Clements Thanks. I have not used Python 3, but saw somewhere about some of the changes between 2.x.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus You can try it yourself with (I think) 2.6+ (might be 2.7 though - that got most of the back-ports) with a `from __future__ import print_function` - just expect a lot of code to break :)

Comment: @octopusgrabbus Here's the link to the [v3 print function docs](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/functions.html#print), my answer below also shows some examples. [PEP 3105](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/) has also more info in the print function.

Comment: you don't want a whitespace in there for clarity? i.e. print("Nope, that is not a two. That is a ", x)

Comment: @jheriko `print` implicitly adds a space between each of its arguments.  If you add one yourself, two spaces will be printed.  In Python 3, you can use the `sep` keyword argument to control this behaviour.

Answer (score 125):

In **Python 2.x** just put a `,` at the end of your `print` statement. If you want to avoid the blank space that `print` puts between items, use `sys.stdout.write`.

```
import sys

sys.stdout.write('hi there')
sys.stdout.write('Bob here.')
```

yields:

```
hi thereBob here.
```

Note that there is *no newline* or *blank space* between the two strings.

In **Python 3.x**, with its [print() function](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/functions.html#print), you can just say

```
print('this is a string', end="")
print(' and this is on the same line')
```

and get:

```
this is a string and this is on the same line
```

There is also a parameter called `sep` that you can set in print with Python 3.x to control how adjoining strings will be separated (or not depending on the value assigned to `sep`)

E.g.,

**Python 2.x**

```
print 'hi', 'there'
```

gives

```
hi there
```

**Python 3.x**

```
print('hi', 'there', sep='')
```

gives

```
hithere
```

Comment: sys.stdout.write works oddly. I don't know the syintax for it, could you give me an example of a simple sys.stdout.write command and its output?

Comment: import sys

sys.stdout.write('hi there')
sys.stdout.write('Bob here.')
I copypaste that into my python and it gives absolutely no output when i press enter. Can this only be used inside a def function() or something?

Comment: @Javicobos try adding this `sys.stdout.flush()` .. perhaps your IO doesn't get flushed.

Comment: Working now, I needed to put first: import sys (press enter)and then the write.stdout.sys stuff. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 24):

If you're using Python 2.5, this won't work, but for people using 2.6 or 2.7, try

```
from __future__ import print_function

print("abcd", end='')
print("efg")
```

results in

```
abcdefg
```

For those using 3.x, this is already built-in.

Comment: Excellent! This is very useful for writing code that is compatible with both versions and will give the same results under both python 2 and python 3!

Answer (score 13):

You simply need to do:

```
print 'lakjdfljsdf', # trailing comma
```

However in:

```
print 'lkajdlfjasd', 'ljkadfljasf'
```

There is implicit whitespace (ie `' '`).

You also have the option of:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write('some data here without a new line')
```

Comment: The import sys; sys.stdout.write method has the advantage of working unchanged on Python 2.x and Python 3.x.

Comment: import sys
sys.stdout.write('some data here without a new line') 
this gives no output at all, I don't understand sys.stdout.write...

Comment: @Javicobos because you have to `sys.stdout.flush()` after. `sys.stdout` is a buffered stream... It just so happens the print statement calls a flush implicitly.

Comment: In an attempt to make it clearer `some_file_like_object.write()` writes to the buffer. The buffer is only written when full or flushed or closed. stdin and stdout are buffered but stderr is not. `print` is basically `sys.stdout.write('lkjsflajfsd\n')`.

Answer (score 5):

Utilize a trailing comma to prevent a new line from being presented:

```
print "this should be"; print "on the same line"
```

Should be:

```
print "this should be", "on the same line"
```

In addition, you can just attach the variable being passed to the end of the desired string by:

```
print "Nope, that is not a two. That is a", x
```

You can also use:

```
print "Nope, that is not a two. That is a %d" % x #assuming x is always an int
```

You can access additional [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) regarding string formatting utilizing the `%` operator (modulo).