# Is it possible to print without new line or space?

Tags: python, printing

Let's say that I want to print 'hello' by 2 different print statements.

Like:

```
print "hel" 
print "lo"
```

But python automatically prints new line so if we want it in the same line we need to -

```
print "hel"**,**
```

Here's the problem - the , makes a space and I want it connected. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: avoid new line with print command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266068/python-avoid-new-line-with-print-command)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `print` *function*

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print('hel', end=''); print('lo', end='')
hello
```

Obviously the semicolon is in the code only to show the result in the interactive interpreter.

The `end` keyword parameter to the `print` function specifies what you want to print after the main text. It defaults to `'\n'`. Here we change it to `''` so that nothing is printed on the end.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.write('hel');sys.stdout.write('lo')
hello
```

Comment: +1 for those too far in the past to use `from __future__ import print_function`.

Comment: @chepner I found out they even have this in 2.6... I doubt anybody will ever **need** this :( However I'm *unfortunately* addicted to the `print` statement so at least with this I don't need to use the function instead

Comment: Think older :) CentOS only moved from 2.4 to 2.6 in their v6 release, and they are still supporting the 5.x series.