# How to split rows while printing a pattern in Python

Tags: python

Input: 4, 4
output expected:

```
****
*..*
*..*
****
```

My output:

```
*
*
*
*
*
.
.
*
*
.
.
*
*
*
*
*
```

My code:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
         for j in range(1, 5):
            if i == 1 or i == 4 or j == 1 or j == 4:
                print("*")
            else:
                print(".")
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266068/python-avoid-new-line-with-print-command

Comment: You are also not taking care of any input in your code.

Comment: yeah i'm sorry. I just joined this community so i hope you pardon my error. I'll be more careful  the next time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print in Python without newline or space?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space)

Answer (score 3):

For a start you could try to do this:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    for j in range(1, 5):
        if i == 1 or i == 4 or j == 1 or j == 4:
            print"*",
        else:
            print".",
    print ''
```

The ',' stops the print command from printing a `\n`.

**UPDATE:**
Then, of course, add the line break after a completed row.

Comment: You don't need `''` in `print ''` in Python 2.x :) `print` is enough.

Comment: Thanks! it is kind of a "good style" for me personally. But maybe I change that into an even better style ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is in a line using reduce:

```
import sys
reduce(lambda x,z:reduce(lambda x,y : sys.stdout.write("*") if y == 1 or y == 4 or z==1 or z==4 else sys.stdout.write("."),range(1,5),None)or sys.stdout.write("\n"),range(1,5),None)
```

O/P :

```
****
*..*
*..*
****
```

Else try your way with loops:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
     for j in range(1,5):
             if i==1 or j==1 or i==4 or j==4:
                     sys.stdout.write("*")
             else:
                     sys.stdout.write(".")
     sys.stdout.write("\n")
```

Same O/P

Comment: Reduce definitely takes lesser time than for loops. So this should be better

Comment: hey yeah it is a bit advanced for me but i looked at it through the net and i got a vague idea of how it works. Nevertheless , thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can store the output in a variable and only print it in the outside loop:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
     line = ""
     for j in range(1, 5):
        if i == 1 or i == 4 or j == 1 or j == 4:
            line = line + "*"
        else:
            line = line + "."
     print line
```

gives as output:

```
****
*..*
*..*
****
```

Comment: Thank you , that was helpful