# Update clock in program Python without creating new line

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, clock

I am creating a program for Raspberry Pi where, in Command Line, the program displays the date and time as shown below and I want to add a repeat or update so the date and time are current after the program begins. This code came off a online tutorial and I want to mess around with it and hit a dead end. I am currently learning Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
now = time.strftime("%c")
print "current date and time " + time.strftime("%c")
```

Comment: because you need to delete `In [5]:`. It was just showing the work from ipython. All you need is `datetime.datetime.now()` and assign that for variable if you like.

Comment: And line with  `Out [5]:` ...

Comment: '#!/usr/bin/python

    import time
    now = time.strftime("%c")
    print "current date and time " + time.strftime("%c")

import datetime
    datetime.datetime.now()

    datetime.datetime.now()
    datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 11, 11, 0, 37, 518511)'

it doesn't update

Comment: see edited answer. It doesn't updated because it's too quick, only microseconds could be displayed

Comment: Related: [python: how to overwrite the previous print to stdout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419389/python-how-to-overwrite-the-previous-print-to-stdout)

Comment: @J.Gill did you have access to solving this?

Comment: @AntonProtopopov, the code works but doesn't help with my dilemma. I am currently trying another way that has just occurred to me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @J.Gill btw, you could accept an answer if it satisfied your question

Answer (score 2):

The following code will print time in the same place every second:

```
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(1.0)
    print("\r" + str(time.time()), end="")
```

Comment: I have tried the code separately and the equal sign in the final line is apparently a syntax error.

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

You could use `datetime` module:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now()

In [5]: datetime.datetime.now()
Out[5]: datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 11, 11, 0, 37, 518511)
```

**EDIT**

Try to use following script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import datetime
import time

a = datetime.datetime.now()
time.sleep(1)
b = datetime.datetime.now()
print(b-a)
```

Comment: Would that update the time repeatedly until program is closed?

Comment: Of course. You could try that several times in python console and will see the results

Comment: Thank you. This helps very much.

Comment: I have hit a slight problem. It keeps saying syntax error for line 3. Not sure if that is just me.

Comment: @J.Gill could you post that line and edit question for that?

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266068/python-avoid-new-line-with-print-command):

You can use a trailing comma to avoid a newline being printed:

```
print "this should be",
print "on the same line"
```