# How to ignore the next line in python

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to print something like this

```
*
* *
* * *
* * * *
```

Here is my code

```
while 1:
    n=int(input("Enter the N"))
    if n<3:
        print("Wrong Input")
        continue
    else:
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            for j in range(1,i+1):
                print("x")
```

I refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266068/python-avoid-new-line-with-print-command) but I am not able to achieve this.
Can you please help me how can I achieve this?
Thank you

Comment: in python3 is print() fuction with next args:  

`print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)`  

so printing without newlines:  

`print("x", end="")`

Comment: thanks for sharing such  informations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example:

```
for i in range(5): 
     print('* '* i)

*
* *
* * *
* * * *
```

**EDIT**

Or you could use `map` functions which is faster:

```
print('\n'.join(map(lambda x: '* ' * x, range(5))))
```

**Timing**

```
In [25]: %timeit print('\n'.join(map(lambda x: '* ' * x, range(5))))
1000 loops, best of 3: 289 us per loop

In [26]: %timeit for i in range(5): print('* '*i)
1000 loops, best of 3: 444 us per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Or something like this as well might work:

```
>>> n = 5
>>> s = '\n'.join('*' * i for i in range(5))
>>> print(s)

*
**
***
****
```

Or wrap it in a function definition and pass it any character you want with any number you need:

```
>>> def my_print(c, n):
        s = '\n'.join(c * i for i in range(n+1))
        return s

>>> my_string = my_print('^', 10)
>>> print(my_string)


^
^^
^^^
^^^^
^^^^^
^^^^^^
^^^^^^^
^^^^^^^^
^^^^^^^^^
^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: You could omit `[]` brackets in your `join` function and use generator instead of `list comprehension`