# Hangman help: invalid print statement

Tags: python

My Hangman code has errors on line 40 , line 40

```
print ('_'+ end=' ')
```

My code:

```
import time
import random
print('Lets play hangman')
print("""
       _______
       |    |
       |    O
       |    |
       |  \- -/
       |    |
       |   | |
       |  |   |
   ____|____
   """)



random_words = ['string', 'loop', 'python', 'print', 'run' , 'graphics window', 'variable', 'iteration', 'modules', 'module', 'input', 'logic', 'output    ']
time.sleep(2)
print ("What level would you like to play at? Too bad, you get random! Better type it in tho...")
level_of_difficulty = "Random"
time.sleep(2)
print ("The program is now generating your word...")
if level_of_difficulty == 'Random':
    generated_word = random.choice(random_words)

guessed = ''

lives = 7


while lives > 0:

    missed = 0
    print()
    for letter in generated_word:
        if letter in guessed:
            print("Congrats ya dumb animal, you got one")
        else:
            print ('_'+ end=' ')
            missed = missed + 1
    if missed == 0:
        print ('\n\nYou win!')  
        quit()
        break
    guess=input("Well what are you waiting for? guess a letter!:")

    guessed = guessed + guess
    if guess not in generated_word:
        print ('\n People like you are the reason why the human race will fail')
        print ('Fool')
    lives = lives - 1 
    missed = missed + 1

    print('your new lives value is ' + str(lives))

    if lives < 7:
        print('''   _______
   |    |   ''')
        if lives < 6:
            print('   |    O    ') 
            if lives < 5:            
                print('   |    |    ')
            if lives < 4:
                print('   |  \- -/  ')
            if lives < 3: 
                print('   |    |    ')
            if lives < 2:
                print('   |   | |  ')
            if lives < 1:
                print('   |  |   | ')
            if lives == 0:
             print('___|___      ')

             print('Game Over Boi')
             print('The secret word was ' + str(generated_word) + "fool")
             quit()
```

Comment: what version of python are you using, and what is the exact error message?

Comment: lemme check on that

Comment: Well, you haven't actually asked a question. You've basically just said, "here's my code, figure out what's wrong." What you should do instead is say, here's my code; i'm getting an error on line XXX, and here's the error message, and here's what I've tried to do to fix it. In other words: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i am using python in the Enthought Canopy 1.6.4(64 bit)

Comment: `print ('_'+ end=' ')` is a syntax error. You probably just forgot a comma or accidentally typed it as `+` instead, you will want to do: `print ('_', end=' ')`.

Comment: @TimothyJohnson hate is the wrong word, but there are a few things wrong with your post. firstly: please include a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example (the only thing missing is the `minimal` part). secondly, don't call for sympathy with phrases like "I'm new to $Language or $Concept". thirdly, include the errors you're getting, don't just say that you're getting errors. and, lastly: don't ever write things like `please help me, um... yeah`.

Comment: %run "C:/Users/mynamehere/hangboi.py"
  File "C:\Users\mynamehere\hangboi.py", line 40
    print ('_'+ end=' ')
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Spencer Wieczorek,i changed it, but it still says something is wrong, a little arrow is pointing at the equals symbol but i need that

Comment: @TimothyJohnson if you're using python 2.x you can't pass `end=` as an argument to the print function.

Comment: Well, i got a buncha downvotes and still cant figure out how to fix it, thank you for trying to help me @wpercy and Spencer Wieczorek and roganjosh

Comment: @TimothyJohnson As @wpercy mentioned this means you using python 2. Which doesn't support the `end` keyword on the `print` function. In that case just remove it and do `print '_',`. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266068/python-avoid-new-line-with-print-command) on how to not have `print` give a new line for python 2 (which is why the commas is at the end).

Answer (score 0):

> so here is some code that partially belongs to me

This appears to be the root of the problem. The main issue aside from a type is the use of Python 3 functionality when you are using Python 2.

```
print ('_'+ end=' ')
```

Aside from the typo that `+` needs to be a `,`. In Python 2 the `end` keyword is not used for print, which is only used in python 3. Instead you can do the same thing in Python 2 by doing:

```
print '_',
```

The next issue will be with line:

```
guess=input("Well what are you waiting for? guess a letter!:")
```

This will give you a error because in Python 2 it tries to evaluate what you entered as an expression instead of a string. Instead you will need to do:

```
guess=raw_input("Well what are you waiting for? guess a letter!:")
```

With both these fixes you will have a [working game](https://repl.it/repls/SlimyLastingShell). Although you may want to add in a way to see what letters the user got right.