# how to get the output in the same line python

Tags: python

I'm trying to send a "scammer" a bunch of fake email and passwords but i get this output:

```
Milan
91@protonmail.com
```

this is the script:

```
import requests
import random

val = 1
url = 'https://repens.serveo.net/login.php'

while val == 1:
   file = open("/home/user/Documents/scam/names.json").readlines()
   random_name = random.choice(file)
   random_number = random.randint(0, 99)
   email_provider = ["@yahoo.com", "@gmail.com", "@walla.com"]
   random_email_provider = random.choice(email_provider)
   name = random_name
   username = "%s%s%s" % (name, random_number, random_email_provider)
   password = random.randint(0, 9999999)
   print(username)

    requests.post(url, allow_redirects=False, data={
        'username': username,
        'password': password    })
```

this is what my names file look like:

Liam
   Noah
   William 
   James
   Logan

I also tried:

[
   "Liam",
   "Noah",
   "William",
   "James",
   "Logan",
]

Comment: try a `.strip()` on the `random_name`

Comment: There may be a `/n` new line character in username.  Strip it off as @chris mentioned

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: avoid new line with print command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266068/python-avoid-new-line-with-print-command)

Comment: Share your `names.json` file

Answer (score 1):

to get the 3 strings appended in a single line, you need to get the name without the next line character. You are getting the name from a file which is split by `readlines()`. You can put the names in a space separated format so you can get your names like this:

```
names = list(map(file.read().split()))
```

you could also do something like this for getting your names from the file:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
```

reference : [How to read a text file into a string variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369219/how-to-read-a-text-file-into-a-string-variable)

Answer (score 1):

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYu9t.jpg)

```
import requests
import random
import string
import json
import os


# setting variables
chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@#$%^&*()'
random.seed = (os.urandom(1024))


# setting up different domain extensions
domain = ['.com', '.gov', '.us', '.edu', '.org', '.ru', '.tw', '.live', '.io', '.blog', '.biz', '.blog', '.co']


# url to overflow
url = 'https://www.stealmylogin.com/demo.html'

# loading and reading json files
names = json.loads(open('names.json').read())
org = json.loads(open('domain.json').read())

# setting up random users and password
for name in names:
    name_extra = ''.join(random.choice(string.digits))
    userId = name.lower() + name_extra + '@' + random.choice(org) + random.choice(domain)
    userPassword = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(8))

# sending user/password to url above
    requests.post(url, allow_redirects=False, data={
        'auid2yjauysd2uasdasdasd': userId,
        'kjauysd6sAJSDhyui2yasd': userPassword
    })


# print the results  - example: sending username noah8@HIPHOP.edu and password ankCRzk8
    print('sending username %s and password %s' % (userId, userPassword)).
```