# How do I make the output all print in one line?

Tags: python, printing

This is the code:

```
#swap capitalizations 
def swap_cases(word):
    for char in word:
        if char.upper() == char:
            b = char.lower()
            print(b)
        else:
            c = char.upper()
            print(c)
```

This is it's output:

```
h
I
i
```

I want it to appear like:

```
hIi
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: avoid new line with print command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266068/python-avoid-new-line-with-print-command)

Comment: `print` has a number of arguments, one is its `end` `print(...,end='')` another way is to hold your variables in a container and print them and use the `sep` argument and set it to `=''`

Answer (score 0):

just try this:

```py
print(something, end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding `end = ""`  parameter to `print` it won't go next line like below :

```
def swap_cases(word):
    for char in word:
        if char.upper() == char:
            b = char.lower()
            print(b,end = "")
        else:
            c = char.upper()
            print(c,end = "")
```

Hope it helps <3

Comment: Thank you soo much, this really did help :)

Comment: @HappyHogan goodluck mate <3

Answer (score 0):

This will print `''` as ending char for chars in a middle of the word, and '\n' for the last char.

```py
def swap_cases(word):
    for i, char in enumerate(word):
        end = '\n' if i == (len(word) - 1) else ''
        if char.upper() == char:
            b = char.lower()
            print(b, end=end)
            else:
                c = char.upper()
                print(c, end=end)
```

so, you will get:

`'hIi\n'` instead of just `'hIi'`